# Remote desktop connection color not proper

Tags: remote-desktop, remote

I'm using Lubuntu 13.10. I have installed Remmina in it. When I connect to remote connection which is Windows Server 2008 the display is not proper. It has different colour some weird colours. I have updated video drivers.

Comment: just a quick related note. I'd not seen the 'color depth' setting on the profile for my connection, and I realised after reading this that the profile box scrolls; the color depth option was there, but hidden. The scroll isn't obvious when using a high DPI screen.

Answer (score 14):

Launch Remmina , right click your connection and click edit. In the remote desktop preference window, change the color depth to **true color (32bpp)** and save the settings. Reconnect and you are done.

Comment: Never heard of remmina before, but glad I did today. Finally can see proper mouse cursor and colors with a remote desktop application.  Thanks.

Comment: There's no connection, I just type the host into the box.  I tried to open preferences under the main menu, but it doesn't show color depth anywhere...

Comment: If you right-click Remmina instead of opening it then __Create a New Connection Profile__ you'll find the Color depth option in there

Comment: Thank you so much! 2 years using Remmina like a assho&*!

Answer (score 2):

I get the same problem due to 32 bit screen on Linux and 24 bit on Windows server 2008 r2.

```
$ rdesktop hostname
WARNING: Remote desktop does not support colour depth 24; falling back to 16
```

If I instead run

```
rdesktop -a 32 hostname
```

I get no such warning.

Comment: Also when using remote desktop to Windows the aero style gets disabled by default which will make it look slightly different.